# UISegmentedControl selectedSegmentStyle 7 and App Store approval

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, iphone-privateapi

Because Apple's APIs lack in customization of UISearchBar's scope bar (that is, I want to change its frame which to my knowledge is impossible), I had to create a scope bar myself using a UISegmentedControl inside of a UIView. I've gotten it to a point where it looks exactly the same as a regular scope bar. I accomplished this by setting the UISegmentedControl's segmentedControlStyle to 7, which is a "hidden" (as in, non-documented) style that makes a segmented control look like the scope bar.

Now the question is: will this be approved in the App Store? I'm not really using any private API, I'm just setting a property to a value different from any of the suggested values. I'm not using any undocumented/private classes or methods, so I think/hope (hope because I have no idea how else I could implement this scope bar mimicking) I should be fine. Anybody else have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up: my app just got accepted while this code was still in there, so apparently it's no problem.